# How to install Bower component from Stash repo with JSPM

Tags: bower, jspm

My client uses Stash (which it seems has been renamed [Bitbucket Server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server)) to host project repositories. We use a private [Bower registry](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) for our private libraries.

In this new project I am building, I am using JSPM. I have used [jspm-git to create a stash registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspm-git#create-a-new-jspm-git-registry). Getting the public libraries such as jQuery, Angular and Lodash obviously works fine.

I get into an issue when I run this:

```
jspm install mapped-name=stash:project-name/lib-name
```

Obviously the actual lib names are redacted to respect my client's intellectual property.

This is the error I get:

```
warn Error on build
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
     at Object.posix.isAbsolute (path.js:479:15)
     at Object.posix.normalize (path.js:461:26)
     at GitLocation.build ([REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm-git/git.js:426:17)
     at [REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm/lib/registry.js:117:30
     at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch ([REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:493:16)
     at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback ([REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:505:17)
     at [REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1001:13
     at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush ([REDACTED]/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I do not know if I forgot a step, or if I misconfigured something, or if there is even a bug with JSPM or jspm-git. Any guidances to help me debug this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a missing [`publishConfig`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#publishconfig) entry in the `package.json` file.

[I had asked this question as well in the jspm-git repo](https://github.com/Orbs/jspm-git/issues/25), and a collaborator seems to agree that improving the error message could provide guidance. Some improvement to look forward to?

I hope this thread is of use to anyone that faces a similar issue.